# How can I update the same SQL Database in 3 different servers?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, copy-paste, auto-update

I am working on a project that uses SQL (2008 R2) databases in a specific server.

The project needs to be in 3 different servers.

I work and make changes to the database in one server and then have to manually copy the database's info and take it to the other two servers.

Any suggestions on how to make this procedure faster and automatic?

Comment: Why 3 different servers? If we had more info we could offer suggestions to solve your real problem...

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL Compare. Or you could treat your database changes correctly as code and write them in scripts (and save in source control) and deploy them like any other code for the same branch.